# Refresh Owl Carousel slider

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

We are using owl slider in tabbing but its not working when moving to another tab and again come back to the tab of the slider.

Slider all items hide when coming back to slider tab.

We have tried below code but its not working.

```
    var owl = $('.frame_wrapper .options-list');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 2
            },
            300: {
                items: 3
            },
            600: {
                items: 5
            },
            1000: {
                items: 6
            }
        }
    });

owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `$owl` variable here?

Comment: Please check my updated question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if somebody is looking for the help. Owl2 doesn't have re-init options. You can use workaround - trigger "destroy.owl.carousel" event and then initialize it again:

```
function reinit() {
  var el = $('.frame_wrapper .options-list');
  el.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
  el.owlCarousel({...});
}
```